# where,when and how convert DTO to/from Entity

Tags: java, architecture

I have project in which i have

- A persistence layer
- Business layer
- Presentation layer

and also I have DTO for every Entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_config")
public class InsuranceConfiguration {
```

and DTO

```
public class InsuranceConfigurationDTO {
```

from architecture perspective
what is the best practice to convert DTO to/from Entity ?

In which layer the conversion should take place?

Should I put the conversion methods inside the DTO/Entity or in separate class ?

Comment: Any answer to this question would be an opinion. I, for one, suggest that you should convert DTO to Entity whenever it logically passes from one system layer to another. "When" or "Where" it happens is entirely up to you to decide.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, what is the best practice?

Comment: Does it matter? Best practice is an opinion. Opinions change and are not useful in context of an SO answer. Oh, and different system building styles follow different best practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should introduce interface layers between the web/service/persistence layer and avoid transitive dependencies. And the transformation logic should not be included in the DTO's rather in a different class, but that's my opinion.

For better understanding, I created a simple UML for this:[image: Might not the best UML in the history of UML diagrams]

(PS.: I could post this project to github if needed)

Comment: you should write article about it and submit it online

Comment: hi Tacsiazuma, could you give us a concrete example? say in C# or C++? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[here is a link](https://www.javaskool.com/about/47-blog/javaskool-category/j2ee-category/j2eedesignpattern/376-j2eedpchap16) where you get to know about the **TOA** design pattern. I think this is what you looking for. Here you call a dao class and after you get an object or list of object you can call a Dozer mapper which you can use for convert from entity to dto and it is may be in util package or mapper package. I think the best is the Business layer or may be the Persistence...but of course not the Presentation..

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of implementing Tacsiazuma's design, it's [here](https://github.com/pamanes/servicearchitecture)